# How can I make ng2-charts vertical bar-chart horizontally scroll-able?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng2-charts

**Problem statement:**
I'm trying to make `ng2-charts` bar chart horizontally `scrollable` because I will receive data from API which is not limited. *If Data values at x-axis grow over certain limit labels at x-axis starts to overlap and I don't want to skip any label, therefore, I want to make my chart Horizontally `scrollable`*.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Take parent div and inside that div add your chart, make parent div width:100%, and chart overflow-x: auto;

Try this, I think this will help you

Comment: @CryptexTechnologies No it doesn't help chart's canvas element is showing responsive behavior.

Comment: did you get any proper solution? i'm also facing same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styles.

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;">
<div class="chart-wrapper" style="height:300px">
<canvas baseChart width="3" height="1"
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [colors] = "[barChartColors]"
    [legend]="'true'"
    [chartType]="'bar'"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```